# How to scale up or out persistent actors for better throughput?

Tags: akka

Is it possible to use persistent actor with router such as to scale out? If you have elasticity with persistent actor you have a problem with your event sourcing.

Hence I wonder how to scale up or out persistent actors for better throughput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit too open to answer directly, though generally there's two things you can do for starters:

For improving a Persistent Actor's throughput there's techniques you can use inside it already, i.e. using [persistAsync](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#Relaxed_local_consistency_requirements_and_high_throughput_use-cases) which batches up updates into one batch sent to the Journal.

PersistentActors can be easily scaled-out by using them together with [ClusterSharding](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-sharding.html) which allows to start actors for given ids (and shard ids) on independent nodes - which sales out the load to those.

Of course for tuning raw throughput of message persisting, you definitely must pick a fast serialization format and configure it as explained in the docs on [schema evolution](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence-schema-evolution.html).

Lastly, but very importantly, you should pick a [Journal implementation](http://akka.io/community/) which will scale to your needs. Cassandra is a popular choice, however you'll need to run at least 3 nodes for it to make sense I'd say.